# Does jquery checkbox tree support the ability to programatically expand using class selectors instead of Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, checkboxtree

I am using the [jquery checkboxtree plugin](http://checkboxtree.googlecode.com/svn/tags/checkboxtree-0.5.2/index.html) which works great.  I have a situation where I want to programmatically expand certain nodes.

I see that I can do by Id as in the example:

```
$('#tabs-5-expand').click(function(){ 
    $('#tree5').checkboxTree('expand', $('#tabs-5-node23')); 
 });
```

and I was hoping that I could expand multiple nodes using a class name like this

```
$('#tabs-5-expand').click(function(){ 
    $('#tree5').checkboxTree('expand', $('.bluetabs')); 
 });
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Does anyone know if there is a way to programatically expand or collapse nodes here using class selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6ofyfzx/) and uncomment the handlers, one at a time. The right way to do it, is to iterate the
array of the elements. Check comments for more.

```
<ul id="tree6">
    <li><input type="checkbox" checked><label>Root</label>
        <ul>
            <li class="bluetabs"><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1</label>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.1</label></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><input type="checkbox" checked><label>Node 2</label>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.1</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2</label></li>
                    <li class="bluetabs"><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.3</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.3.1</label></li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.3.2</label></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>   
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.4</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.5</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.6</label></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>           
</ul>

<button id="test">Press to expand</button>


$('#tree6').checkboxTree({
    initializeChecked: 'expanded',
    initializeUnchecked: 'collapsed'
}); 


//If all the bluetabs are collapsed this will work. If you expand one of the blue ones, then it won't work for the other.
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('#tree6').checkboxTree( 'expand', $('.bluetabs') );
});


//This will work regardless
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('.bluetabs').each(function() {
        $('#tree6').checkboxTree( 'expand', $(this) );
    });
});
```